# trying to set a value to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to write a simple script to do git add, commit and push.

```
@echo off
SET operation=%1
SET opParam=%2
SET mainBranch=dev/1.1

if %operation%==fire (
    for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do set branchName=%%i
    if %opParam%.==. (
        SET opParam="autogeneratedmessage"
        @echo on
        echo %opParam%
        @echo off
    ) else (
        SET opParam="%opParam%"
        @echo on
        echo %opParam%
        @echo off
    )
    git add -A 
    git commit -m %opParam%
    git push origin %branchName%
)
```

So the problem is when the second parameter is empty, it fails to set the value of `opParam` to `autogeneratedmessage` at line 9.

Here is what i have tried so far to set the opParam:

```
SET opParam=""autogeneratedmessage""
SET opParam="autogeneratedmessage"
SET "opParam=autogeneratedmessage"
```

I really can't see what im doing wrong here. It seems like a simple issue but i've been on this for half an hour now.

Comment: @Squashman yup that was it... I had no idea what the heck a delayed expansion was lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had enable the delayed expansion in that block and reference my variable using `!` instead of `%`.

```
if %operation%==fire (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do set branchName=%%i
    if %opParam%.==. (
        SET opParam="autogenerated"
        @echo on
        echo !opParam!
        @echo off
    ) else (
        SET opParam="%opParam%"
        @echo on
        echo %opParam%
        @echo off
    )
    git add -A 
    git commit -m !opParam!
    git push origin %branchName%
)
```